# I need a command to know if a file is linking to another file

Tags: shell-script, symlink, command

How I can know if `file1` is a symbolic link to a `file2`?
I need an if condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-h` test to determine whether a file is a symbolic link, and [`-ef`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/File-characteristic-tests.html#File-characteristic-tests) to check if it links to a given file (note that `-ef` isn’t [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)):

```
if [ -h file1 ] && [ file1 -ef file2 ]; then
    echo 'file1 is a symbolic link and equivalent to file2'
fi
```

Comment: I suppose both files could be two different names for the same symbolic link too, pointing to some third pathname, but that might be a too weird edge case.